# build script in package.json using webpack with --config flag as

Tags: npm

In my package.json I'm trying to use `webpack` in a script but it keeps failing.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "mocha 'src/**/test*.coffee' --watch --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.dist.config.js"
  },
```

the scripts `start` and `test` works as expected but when running `npm build` in terminal I'm getting nothing:

```
➜  client git:(master) ✗ npm build
➜  client git:(master) ✗
```

When running the command manually, things happen:

```
➜  client git:(master) ✗ webpack --config webpack.dist.config.js
Hash: 9274a04acd39605afc25
Version: webpack 1.9.10
Time: 5206ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  5.23 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
 [349] ../config.js 181 bytes {0} [built]
    + 413 hidden modules
➜  client git:(master) ✗
```

Have I miss understod how npm scripts are suppose to work?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use: `npm run build`

Reason: `npm start` & `npm test` are shortcuts for `npm run start` & `npm run test`, for any other npm tasks, you have to specify "run"

Answer (score 9):

Run `npm run build`.

`start` and `test` are built in scripts for `npm`. `build` however is a custom script and thus needs to be invoked with `npm run build`.

You can find out more about npm's scripts [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)